# How to pass long as string on url for json response in loopj

Tags: android, loopj, asynchttpclient

Just started learning loopj. how to pass long {id} on url as string?

I have a method in client like this,

```
  public static void getAllByIdForSpinner(Context context, String url, Header[] headers, 
        RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
                     client.get(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), headers, params, responseHandler);
                    }
```

and in mainactivity

```
 myRestClient.getAllByIdForSpinner(MainActivity.this, "ExampleRestService/product/" +id, 
                headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]), null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
```

I tried few things. But nothing worked for this method.

Comment: Can't you use String.valueOf(id)

Comment: yeah tried but its failing. Can you please show how to fit it into this method?

Comment: Have you tried to log what's the final string you are getting? And what error you are getting?

Comment: Yes i did. I am not getting response. also in onFailure method my toast displayed failed.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. my logs stops after entering this method and i get failed toast.